# Loading React Sidebar in Parent Component when Child Component Loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React, I'm trying to load a sidebar component in the parent component when a specific child component loads. The first issue I'm having is I keep receiving a TypeError that `this` is not defined. Secondly, cannot get `<Sidebar/>` to load when `<NewPage/>` is loaded. I'd like to also update the title in `main`, but I cannot even get to that point yet until I'm able to get the sidebar to show.

Below is a JSFiddle of the 3 classes I've put together to demonstrate the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/pegues/9d31pah7/

**Below is the main class component code:**

```
class Main extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.titleHandler = this.titleHandler.bind(this);
        this.sidebarHandler = this.sidebarHandler.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            pageTitle: '',
            mounted: false,
            data: [],
            sidebar: false
        }
    }

    // Title Handler
    titleHandler(){
        console.log('Page Title Function Called');
        this.setState({ pageTitle: this.state.pageTitle });
    }

    // Sidebar Handler
    sidebarHandler(){
        console.log('Sidebar Function Called');
        this.setState({ sidebar: !state.sidebar });
    }

    // Load Dashboard
    loadDashboard(){
        ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard/>, document.querySelector('#main-content'));
    }

    // Load New Page
    loadNewPage(){
        ReactDOM.render(<NewPage action={this.sidebarHandler} />, document.querySelector('#main-content'));
    }

    // Render
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="wrapper" className="wrapper">

                <button onClick={this.loadDashboard}>Load Dashboard</button>
                <button onClick={this.loadNewPage}>Load New Page</button>

                {/* Content: Start */}
                <div id="content" className="content">

                    {/* Main: Start */}
                    <div id="main" className="main">

                        <div className="section-title">
                            <h2>{this.state.pageTitle}</h2>
                        </div>

                        {/* Main Content Container: Start */}
                        <div id="main-content" className="main-content container-fluid"></div>
                        {/* Main Content Container: End */}

                    </div>
                    {/* Main: End */}

                    {this.state.sidebar ? <Sidebar/> : null}

                </div>
                {/* Content: End */}

            </div>
        );
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />,document.querySelector('#root'));
```

**Below is the NewPage class component:**

```
class NewPage extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageTitle: 'New Page',
            sidebar: false
        };

        this.props.action.bind(this);
    }

    // Component Will Mount
    componentWillMount(){}

    // Component Did Mount
    componentDidMount(){}

    // Component Will Unmount
    componentWillUnmount(){}

    // Render
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                New Page Content...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: pass a method to toggle the sidebar state value to the child component and call that in the child component's `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` methods.

Comment: I'm trying to pass a method to the child component by doing `ReactDOM.render(<NewPage action={this.sidebarHandler} />, document.querySelector('#main-content'));`, but because of doing that I'm getting a TypeError saying `this is undefined`. Please review the JSFiddle. The method is being passed within the `loadNewPage()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow functions in class properties to avoid binding `this.handleCardClick = this.handleCardClick.bind(this)`.

In your case, you forgot binding `loadNewPage` etc.

```js
class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    pageTitle: "",
    mounted: false,
    data: [],
    sidebar: false
  };

  titleHandler = () => { ... }

  sidebarHandler = () => { ... }

  loadDashboard = () => { ... }

  loadNewPage = ()  => { ... }
...
}
```

Moreover, you are not referencing the `state` in `sidebarHandler`:

```
sidebarHandler = () => {
    console.log('Sidebar Function Called');
    this.setState({ sidebar: !this.state.sidebar }); // Not state.sidebar
}
```

There are many more mistakes in your code, like not using `props.action` that passed to `NewPage` and so on.

Use current sandbox with toggled `Dashboard`, `NewPage` and `Sidebar` to review your code.

[image: Edit ywy93ykwoz]

Comment: I was in a meeting, so sorry I didn't reply sooner. Thank you very much for your help with this. I reviewed your CodeSandbox example, and it helps me out tremendously. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I see you removed the constructor(props) and super(props). I've read that this is personal preference, but not sure why. Could you please explain why you didn't use the constructor in the main class?

Comment: React Class Components can be made much more concise using the class field declarations. You can initialize local state without using the constructor and declare class methods by using arrow functions without the extra need to bind them. Anyway using React Hooks is even more concise than classes.

Comment: Hi again Dennis Vash, in your demo you're toggling the `sidebar` using an `onClick` event, `<button onClick={this.props.action}>Toggle Sidebar</button>`. How can `{this.props.action}` be called automatically when `<NewPage/>` is mounted? I tried adding {this.props.action} in `componentDidMount(){}` in the `NewPage` class, but it throws an error: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`. I'm quite new to React, and trying to figure out how these kinds of things work.

Comment: Edit the call back function of `Toggle New Page`: `        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ sidebar: true });
            this.loadNewPage();
          }}
        >` https://codesandbox.io/s/ywy93ykwoz?fontsize=14